# COBOL search logic

Tags: search, cobol, mainframe

I have requirement to search a table using certain
Key fields. Now for set of records that match the key fields. I am able to retrieve data from data
For the key fields that do not match
How to retrieve data from table?

I used search logic in mainframe but am not able to get table records that does not match the key

Comment: [COBOL - SEARCH Statement](https://www.ibmmainframer.com/cobol-tutorial/cobol-search-statement/)

Comment: Hi @rahshree-m and welcome to stackoverflow, please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how this site works and how you can improve your question to get useful answers.
One of the things: what have you tried (code), where is the problem...

Comment: How many entries are in the table? How many key values? Please [edit] your post to include that information along with the code you tried.

Comment: SEARCH returns first matching record to a passed key and the given condition. The condition can be = or NOT =. However, unlike SQL query, SEARCH returns 1 record at most.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote: *I used search logic in mainframe but am not able to get table records that does not match the key*

While `SEARCH` may be used, it is not necessary and may be complicated. That is because the matching condition must be negative as I show below in the code for selecting all records not matching "E".

It is much easier to use one of the conditional statements: `IF` or `EVALUATE`, which may be used for even complicated situations involving multiple key values or multiple fields.

For this example, I created a table with with values "A" through "I". I then used `SEARCH` to allow the display of all records not matching a single key value. I also used `EVALUATE` to allow the display of all records not matching three key values.

Code:

```
   data division.
   working-storage section.
   01 s-key pic x value "E".
   01 m-key-table value "CFI".
     03 m-key pic x occurs 3.
   01 s-table value "ABCDEFGHI".
     03 s-entry pic x occurs 9 indexed idx.

   procedure division.

       display "Records not matching single key "
           quote "E" quote

       perform varying idx from 1 by 1
       until idx > 9
           search s-entry
           at end
               continue
           when s-entry (idx) not = s-key
               display s-entry (idx)   *> or move
           end-search
       end-perform

       display space

       display "Records not matching multiple keys "
           quote "C, F or I" quote

       perform varying idx from 1 by 1
       until idx > 9
           evaluate s-entry (idx)
           when m-key (1)      *> ignore matching keys
           when m-key (2)
           when m-key (3)
               continue
           when other
               display s-entry (idx)   *> or move
           end-evaluate
       end-perform
       goback
       .
```

Output:

```
Records not matching single key "E"
A
B
C
D
F
G
H
I

Records not matching multiple keys "C, F or I"
A
B
D
E
G
H
```